# Dax measure to calculate minimum value with in a group of a complete table

Tags: group-by, powerbi, aggregate, dax, measure

The ask is to create a measure (**not a calculated column using Earlier**), to fetch minimum unit price of a product group by year and "UnitofMeasure" and show them as "UnitPriceMin" against complete list of data in separate column as shown below-

[image]

Comment: In which column is the product group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this below measure.

> I have considered column "Year", "description" and "unitmeasure" for the grouping. You can add/remove columns as per your necessity.

> Considered your table name - "product_details". change it as per your table name.

```
group_wise_min = 

VAR current_row_year = MIN(product_details[year])
VAR current_row_product = MIN(product_details[description])
VAR current_row_unit_measure = MIN(product_details[unitmeasure])

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    MIN(product_details[unitprice]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(product_details),
        product_details[year] = current_row_year
            && product_details[description] = current_row_product
            && product_details[unitmeasure] = current_row_unit_measure
    )
)
```

Output will be as below-

[image]

Comment: Thanks mkRabbani, It worked flawlessly.Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: You are most welcome @Sushant. Nice to see it helped.

Comment: Hi mkRabbani, Is there anyway we can show global minimum in Total section of Table, Right now it is showing blank.

Comment: you can use a separate measure for that.

Comment: Hi mkRabbani, This implementation is giving memory error on 1M rows on web deployment, Probably because it is calculating it for each row in the dataset, By any means can we make it more efficient?

Comment: You can create a Custom Table using GROUP BY. Then join your main table with GROUP BY table. Probably this will increase some performance.

Comment: Yes, but that will be static calculated table and will not change on runtime, I have some dynamic filter which is restricting the data like outlier and others, custom GROUP BY table will be loaded at the start and will remain same.

Comment: @Sushant Why not? This will also refresh run time when ever you have change in source data. I mean the custom table will also update with every refresh of data.